# pc does not boot when pcie card inserted

Tags: motherboard, bios, pci-express

I built a new PC:

Gigabyte GC-WB867D-I - 867MBit W-LAN <--PROBLEM

When I insert this PCIe card, my computer does not boot.

I disabled the Realtek LAN Controller in BIOS, updated BIOS, tried different PCIe slots, etc.

**Update: 28/07/17***  three beeps when card is inserted.

strange behavior: started suddenly (no more modifications), installed dirvers, network was available, restarted, pc did not start again. 
was not repeatable, now pc is only starting with one beep post signal, if the card is removed.

Does anybody have an idea? I believe putting the card in while the PC is running is a bad idea?

(think I will send the card back and buy a asus wifi card, which hopefully is compatible with my asus mainboard...)

**udpdate 30/07/17**

will send the card back, bought an other wifi card, no wifi works fine. slots are not damaged. I think it is an incompatibility between the board and the card. anybody else made similar experiences?

- [Asus Prime B350-Plus MB](https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/PRIME-B350-PLUS/)
- Ryzen 5 1600x Core
- Corsair Vengeance LPX CMK16GX4M2B3200C16R  DDR4 RAM
- Be Quiet Pure Power 600W PSU
- Palit GeForce GTX 1050 Ti KalmX 4 GB GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0

Comment: Putting it in while the machine is running is a bad idea. Have you tried the card on a different machine? Or have you tried a different PCIe card on the machine that you're working on?

Comment: We need to verify that your new Wi-Fi card isn't faulty.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't boot do you mean it didn't POST. Also if your BIOS has a 'verbose' option turn it on and see what comes out of it.

Comment: thanks for your replies. different machine: yes, pc boots without any problems. WiFi Card seems to be ok. and yes - it didn't post. I will try the verbose option at night, when I'm back home. Also, I will install a mainboard speaker, so hopefully I will get some more advices from the mainboard what the problem might be.

Comment: Here's a table of ASUS motherboard beep codes, which matches what your machine is doing? https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1029959

Comment: Does the wireless card support a modern UEFI system? Or does it only supporty the old BIOS firmware?